# Error raised during calls in asterisk server

Tags: asterisk

Today my asterisk could not receive calls for a while. when I checked the asterisk logs, the error below was raising during this period.

```
Purely numeric hostname (1002), and not a peer--rejecting!
```

After I restarted the asterisk the problem solved. **What is the problem?**

Comment: That's the ONLY error you received?

Comment: You have a Dial(SIP/1002) somewhere. This error message would show if there is no defined 1002 in sip.conf as a user/peer... But you have it. Maybe you did some editing and reloaded dialplan without reloading sip.conf. This is the only explanation.